# Angular 9 ivy dist too large for prod build

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-ivy

Medium size project (some 30 lazy loaded modules)
src folder (ts files, assets etc) before compilation takes 2mb.
Dist folder with prod build is 18mb

angular.json

```
"prod": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": true,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "2mb",
              "maximumError": "5mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "6kb"
            }
          ]
        }
```

package.json

```
    {

  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "9.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "9.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "9.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "9.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "9.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "9.0.0",
    "@angular/localize": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "9.0.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "9.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "9.0.0",
    "@stomp/ng2-stompjs": "7.2.0",
    "angular-count-to": "0.0.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "chartist": "^0.11.4",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.5.7",
    "feather-icons": "^4.26.0",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "jwt-decode": "2.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-chartist": "^4.1.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
    "ngx-quill": "^8.1.3",
    "ngx-toastr": "11.2.1",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "quill-image-resize": "^3.0.9",
    "quill-image-resize-module": "^3.0.0",
    "quill-mention": "^2.2.5",
    "rxjs": "6.5.4",
    "terser": "3.14.1",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.1",
    "@angular/cli": "9.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "9.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "9.0.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.13",
    "@types/file-saver": "2.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "file-saver": "2.0.2",
    "rxjs-tslint": "0.1.7",
    "stylelint": "12.0.1",
    "ts-node": "8.5.4",
    "tslint": "5.20.1",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "5.4.0",
    "typescript": "3.6.4",
    "typescript-tslint-plugin": "^0.5.5",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.7.0"
     }
  }
```

Comment: is there any unused dependency installed in your project?

Comment: You can increase the budgets, if your project gets too large. If you want to keep these budgets, you will have to inspect the sizes of those dependencies yourself.

Comment: There are no unused dependecies. package.json is pretty clean.

Comment: https://twitter.com/IgorMinar/status/1233254670316888064 is this helpful to you?

Comment: Turns out @import '~@angular/material/theming'; in scss file is responsible for extra 12mb for production build.